# Link to App Store app developer page with iOS 6?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios6, itunes-app

Is there a way, in iOS 6, to link from an app to a specific developer's page on the App Store app? By that I mean a list showing all the apps by the developer.

There are various ways to link to the store (I am using the Appmosys as the example here) that produce various results:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/appmosys/id331687329 - The link copied from desktop iTunes, opens up the iTunes app on an iOS 6 device, with the developer's page. If you tap on one of their apps, it goes to that app on the App Store app.

http://itunes.com/apps/appmosys - Opens the iTunes app (via Safari) but presents this error message: "Cannot connect to iTunes store".

itms://itunes.com/apps/appmosys - Goes straight to the iTunes app, but same error as above.

itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appmosys - Opens the App Store app, but also presents the same error (screenshot here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6920023/iphone-screenshot.PNG ).

Is there actually a way to do this in iOS 6?

**Bonus points** if you can answer the question and know if the link you provide also works with the affiliate program, http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/. I've already looked at the Link Maker on this page, http://www.apple.com/itunes/link/, but can only produce the standard iTunes link.

**Part B / even more bonus points**

You can link straight to the Reviews tab in the App Store app for an app, but can you also now link straight to the new Related tab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i have a solution for **iOS 5**: 
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appmosys/id331687329

and one for **iOS 6**:
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/artist/appmosys/id331687329

if you use itms-apps:// URLs instead of http:// it will open the app store app on the device, which is less confusing to the user, then going through safari.

Unfortunately i didn't found any single URL that works on iOS 5 and iOS 6. So the [Apple Q&A Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html) is not valid anymore for iOS 6 :-(

**UPDATE:** i just realized that my iOS 5 solution works also on iOS 6 on the iPad, but not on the iPhone with iOS 6. it's getting weirder and weirder....

**UPDATE 2:**

apple just [annonced](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=212013a) the **appstore.com urls** so now you can link to Electronic Arts  Developer Page with http://appstore.com/ElectronicArts

i just tested it and it works for iPad from iOS 5.1 to 6.0 and iPhone from 4.3 to 6.0

so now the [Apple Q&A Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html) is valid!

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the http://appstore.com links open Safari first and itms-apps://appstore.com/ result in "Could not connect to App Store" error. The initial solution works very well - one for iOS 6 and one for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I have a universal app and I needed to open up my developer page, and display the correct apps depending whether the user is using an iPhone, iPod or iPad. The only way I could get this to work correctly was by using the iTunes link maker http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/ results but replaced **https:** with **itms-apps:**

Answer (score 2):

The link like http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewArtist?id=426623392
will be work on any iOS devices and any browsers in Internet also.

The customer will be NOT confused because it is standard link of Apple and  developers using it.

Change just your id. So, it will be http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewArtist?id=XXXXXXXX where XXXXXXXX is your developer id.

This link you can find also in  iTunes App on your desktop by copy the link from button "More Apps by YYYYYYY" on page of any of yours App. There YYYYYYY is  your developer name. Like on this page https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/visual-html-editor-eye-lite/id472624198?mt=8

Comment: It works, but I get this format from iTunes: `https://itunes.apple.com/jp/artist/YYYYYYYY/idXXXXXXXXX?l=en&mt=8_`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to have a CUSTOMIZED "MORE APPS BY US" page inside your app (not exit to AppStore or Safari), then have a look at what I created here (there is downloadable working project):

http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-create-dynamic-more-apps-page.html

The beauty of this is the data is retrieved from iTunes AppStore everytime you open the page in your app, and that you can customize it however you like.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

http://itunes.apple.com/artist/id331687329.

I get to this link by using iTunes on Mac. Search for the company name, click on any app that is made by the company, look for "More iPhone Apps by XXXXX", click on it, then you'll see all apps by this company, right click on the company name and copy link, and you'll get this link.  This link will work with iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems mit links created with http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/

It generates only https links.