# Short AppStore URL - Developers Single URL

Tags: ios, url, app-store, itunes

I've been reading a few things about shortening URLs to the App Store so instead of having a really long, unattractive url, you can like: `AppStore.com/MyAppOrMyCompanyName`

I found that type of url [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1629/_index.html) and there are several ways of linking to dev pages directly in older iOS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557066/link-to-app-store-app-developer-page-with-ios-6?rq=1)...

I'm hoping to use the `Appstore.com/` or `appsto.re/` scheme to make the URL look better and more readable, as well as cutting out the redirect from safari and link straight to the App Store either from my social media (as well as in my games by pressing a button).

There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944489/creating-an-app-store-short-link) about shortening the URLs but I can't see how to use this to a developers page (so it shows all apps) instead of a single application.

Where can I find this/how can I get my company url?

Answer (score 10):

You can now make short link URLs in the form of `apple.co/#####`

In September 2020, Apple released new marketing tools:

[App Store Marketing Tools](https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store/)

Search for your app, and then you can generate a short link, QR code, and download app artwork.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the info from the [Apple Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html).  Make sure you convert all letters to lowercase and remove all spaces.:

```
There are three types of App Store Short Links, in two forms, one for iOS apps, another for Mac Apps:

Company Name

    iOS: http://appstore.com/<companyname> for example, http://appstore.com/apple

    Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/<companyname> for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple

App Name

    iOS: http://appstore.com/<appname> for example, http://appstore.com/keynote

    Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/<appname> for example, http://appstore.com/mac/keynote

App by Company

    iOS: http://appstore.com/<companyname>/<appname> for example, http://appstore.com/apple/keynote

    Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/<companyname>/<appname> for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple/keynote
```

Comment: I linked that article in my question... It doesn't show where to assign a company name or which format name is default for your dev account... I've tried the obvious (my name/company) and it didn't work...

Comment: That's strange, when I try it on my iPhone with my dev account name, it goes to the App Store and lists my apps.